# Finding the image for the fundamental group of a covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am representing $S^1 \vee S^1$ via the following diagram:

[image]

I have the following connected covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$, call it $p: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$, for $X=S^1 \vee S^1$.

[image]

I am having difficulty in computing $p_{*}(\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0))$, where $p_{*}$ indicates the image of the map $p$ under the $\pi_1$ functor.

I know that $\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0) \cong <\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \sigma, \theta, \mu>$ , but my issue lies in finding the images $\alpha, \dots, \mu$ under $p_*$. My naive guess would be that  $\alpha = b, \beta = a^2, \gamma = b^2,  \sigma = a^2,  \theta = b^2,  \mu = a$ but I believe this doesn't respect the basepoint $\tilde{x}_0$.

Answer (score 1):

The concern you mentioned at the end of your post is pretty accurate. It may be helpful to recall how you arrived at the fundamental group of your covering space, this should give you an answer to your question. The computation can be done via the Seifert-Van-Kampten theorem, that inductively gives you the fundamental group your wedge sum. But to make life easier you will change the basepoint at each step, which is possible for path connected spaces. The change of basepoint also has an explicit isomorphism of fundamental groups by picking a path and conjugating your loop by it (so of the form $f \mapsto sfs^{-1}$). For you that means remembering the path you had to chose to get to the loop you want, I think this is the idea you had, that each loop represents a generator. So $p(\alpha )=  b^{-1}a^{-1}bab$, $p(\beta) = b^{-1}aab$ ... . Algebraic Topology by A.Hatcher also gives those Covering spaces as an example.

Edit: forgot to take inverses

Comment: Okay, I see what you have done. You've basically changed basepoints to express the generators in terms of $\tilde{x}$. So we would have $p(\gamma)=b^2), p(\sigma)=a^2, p(\theta)=ab^2a^{-1}$

I also tried applying SVK directly without changing the basepoints and got a similar answer but slightly different. For $\alpha$, for example, I had $p(\alpha)=baba^{-1}b^{-1}$, but I'm assuming this is homotopic to your expression as I have considered the bottom edges instead of the top ones?

Comment: Yes exactly, you also do not need to change the basepoint that is right, I just seem to prefer it for some reason. I am not sure what you mean by homotopic. E.g. the $\alpha$ you and I used do not correspond to the same elements in the fundamental group.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe homotopic isn't the correct terminology, but what I'm trying to say is that when you changed the basepoints, you conjugated by the path that went along the top edges. The other expression I wrote is what you get for $p(\alpha)$ when you change to the same basepoint, but instead go along the bottom edges. It's also what I got when I applied SVK directly without changing the basepoints.

Comment: What I meant to ask is that if instead of the path along the top edges that you used, we used used path along the bottom edges (so $ba$ instead of $b^{-1}a^{-1}$), then we should have the same subgroup for $<p(\alpha), p(\beta), p(\gamma), p(\sigma), p(\theta), p(\mu)$>, no?

Comment: Or at least be conjugate?